# How to test DST change with calendar events

Tags: testing, timezone, icalendar, dst

I have a system that sends ICS to plant events in our customers calendars. Of course, it blew up when we moved to winter time, all events planned before the switch are now offset by one hour.

There are plenty of fixes for me to try out on this very website, it is not my question.

Now, how do I test them ? I tried scheduling an event for next summer (with the unpatched system) and it landed at the right time in my gmail calendar, hinting that the problem only happens at the moment of the time change (9 days ago for me)

So what I need is reproduce "the time change", but I have no clue how to do that. Whether it's summer time or not is decided by Google or Microsoft, I can't really simulate anything on my live calendar...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (And that's just for manual testing. How do I automate a test like this ?)

Comment: If you have set the timezone of the ics event appropriately, then the problem may only be in some users calendars where they have not set their calendar timezone correctly?  There are 3 forms for the DATETIME, local, UTC and TZ.  Sounds like you should be using TZ? https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.3.5

Comment: @anmari Thanks, but as I said, this is not my question. My question is how to test these fixes you're proposing.

Comment: Other than having different devices or website set to different timezones and checking that the expected time shows up? You could just create a bunch of google calendar accounts?  And to check the times when sometimes there are different daylight saving changes you could setup some cities on https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingtime.html